# Reversing the way rows get entered into a data table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a function that makes it so I can select rows of a data table and it keeps track of the rows that I select. However when it returns the other data table, it enters the rows that I select backwards.

So if I select rows `1,2,3` when it returns the data table the rows show as `3,2,1` Here is the function:

```
Private Function getCoordinates()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    Dim r As DataRow
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim selectedItems As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = dgv.SelectedRows

    dt = dgv.DataSource
    dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    dgv.MultiSelect = True

    dt2.Columns.Add("Command")
    dt2.Columns.Add("Position")

    Try
        If selectedItems Is Nothing Then
            For n = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                r("Command") = dt.Rows.Item(n)("Mouse Command")
                r("Position") = dt.Rows.Item(n)("Mouse Position")
                dt2.Rows.Add(r)
            Next

        Else
            For Each selectedItem As DataGridViewRow In selectedItems

                Dim MouseIndex = Convert.ToString(selectedItem.Cells(0).Value)
                Dim CoordIndex = Convert.ToString(selectedItem.Cells(1).Value)
                r = dt2.NewRow()
                r("Command") = MouseIndex
                r("Position") = CoordIndex
                dt2.Rows.Add(r)

            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return dt2

End Function
```

Wsa just wondering how I would make it so that the rows wouldn't get reversed like it does.

Comment: If `selectedItems Is Nothing` you will get an exception because you are using `r` which is an uninitialized `DataRow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just loop backwards:

```
For i As Integer = selectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  Dim selectedItem As DataGridViewRow = selectedItems(i)
  '...
Next
```

Comment: I thought of that solution but what happened if he selects rows in this order 2, 1, 3?

Comment: I never even thought about doing this... you rock!

Comment: @tezzo: Well I think OP would be okay with that. According to the question, problem is that the order is backwards, not that the order does not exactly match the logical order of records. So I thought the solution would be to reverse the order manually. I +1'd your answer though.

Comment: @Neolisk, you're right! I put my attention on the logical order of records but it doesn't explicitely asked!

Answer (score 2):

From [social.msdn.microsoft.com forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ef8a9fbf-8b1b-4ba1-b5b7-f425640fbfc6/order-in-datagridview-multiple-select):

> The first selected DataGridViewRow is listed in the last item in the SelectedRows collection of the DataGridView. This behavior is by design.

You can loop every DataGridViewRow and copy it in the DataTable only if it is selected.

Comment: How would you do that for the selected rows?

Comment: Check .Selected property for every DataGridViewRow in the DataGridView. http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.selected.aspx